# how to put correctly Dynamic Framework to Xcode12.5

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, xcode12, google-cast-sdk

I'm using Xcode12.5 tool.
I just tried to add Dynamic Framework to Xcode but I could see Embed Status that is "Do Not Embed" from Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content.

I have known when I add Dynamic Framework, Embed Status is "Embed & Sign"
but my xcode status is "Do Not Embed"

additional, I changed status from "Do Not Embed" to "Embed & sign" forcibly.
but This way was wrong because build is OK, but it's not working during archiving
So How can I resolve problem..? I want to resolve it!

Answer (score 0):

Use this go to build setting search validate workspace Change it to Yes for both debug and release.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4OWV.png)